# Is this valid AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

Is the "**AND FALSE**" portion proper AMPscript syntax? I came across this kind of statement but am not sure what to think of it.

```
%%[
IF @TableName == "Cornelius" AND FALSE THEN
SET @data = "12345"
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: I've never used AMPscript but it kind of looks like a construct one would use to quickly test if the false condition works as expected, or maybe to disable the if without removing the code.

Comment: Interesting...I think you're right about the disabling part. Just tested it with and without, and it is negating itself. Thanks for mentioning this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's valid -- and easy to test.  I suppose you could use something like this to temporarily disable a conditional.

```
%%[

if 1==1 and false then
  output(concat("<br>true"))
else
  output(concat("<br>false"))
endif

]%%
```

**Output**

`false`

What you *can't* do (and what I think [@Jackson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/55449/jackson-chen) correctly implied) is combine left operands in a conditional.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Didn't know it was a known method for disabling AMPscript.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not accurate. It needs to be written like:

```
%%[
IF @TableName == "Cornelius"
AND @TableName == "FALSE" THEN
SET @data = "12345"
ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is missing from the code.
on the right side of the AND there should be a condition of some kind.
Currently, there isn't.
Right now I would say that this snippet is invalid.
Best regards.